# Get the id of button to Remove a input field on click of minus button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an option field with by default 2 option. I have a button "Add more Option", this will add a input field (containing minus button to remove) dynamically.

I want to remove the particular input field when user clicks minus button.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="index" method="post">     
        <div id="optionsList"class="form-group">
            <label for="options">Options</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="option1" placeholder="M S Dhoni">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="option2" placeholder="Virat Kohli">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="moreOptions">Add More Options</button>
        </div>          
    </form>
</div>
```

**Here is the script  -**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var optionNo = 2;
      $("#moreOptions").click(function(){
        optionNo = optionNo + 1;
        $("#optionsList").append
        ('<div class="input-group" id="inputField' + optionNo +'"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="New option field" id="option' + optionNo +'"><i class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="removeBtn' + optionNo +'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button></i></div>');
      });
      // here i want to write code to remove that input field      
    });
```

**I tried this -**

```
$(".input-group").click(function(){
    const id = this.id;
    $("#id").remove();
  });
```

**Please suggest. Any other way to do this will also be fine.**

Comment: You should keep HTML as short as needed for the questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes instead of worrying about incrementing ID's. That approach gets too complicated to manage sometimes and it isn't needed at all

Simplified append html with new class `remove-btn` instead of id on button:

```
 $("#optionsList").append
        ('<div class="input-group"><input><button class="btn btn-danger remove-btn" type="button"></button></div>');
```

Delegated event listener for any `.remove-btn` added to dom in future

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove-btn', function(){
   // "this" is current button event occurs on
   $(this).closest('.input-group').remove()
})
```

Comment: thank you so much. well explained . this worked too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly don't use `id`'s in dynamically created elements if you are not going to change it's value and end up with multiple elements with the same ID instead use classes. ie.

```
class="removeBtn'
```

Next for dynamically created elements use event bubbling to attach events

```
$("body").on("click", ".removeBtn", function(){
  $(this).closest(".input-group").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you add on the fly the new button you need to delegate the click event to the document:

```
$(document).on('click', ".input-group button", function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.input-group').remove();
});
```

This part: ".input-group button" means: listen for click event related to button element inside an input-group

The [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) used to get the parent div to be removed.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var optionNo = 2;
  $("#moreOptions").on('click', function(e) {
      optionNo = optionNo + 1;
      $("#optionsList").append
      ('<div class="input-group" id="inputField' + optionNo +
      '"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="New option field" id="option' + optionNo +
      '"><i class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="removeBtn' + optionNo +
      '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button></i></div>');
  });
  // here i want to write code to remove that input field
  $(document).on('click', ".input-group button", function(e) {
      $(this).closest('.input-group').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="index" method="post">
        <div id="optionsList"class="form-group">
            <label>Options</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="option1" placeholder="M S Dhoni">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="option2" placeholder="Virat Kohli">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="moreOptions">Add More Options</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" name="button">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code. Hope it helps.

```js
var counter = 1;

$(document).on('click', 'button#moreOptions', function(){
    $("#optionsList").append
('<div class="input-group" style="padding:5px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="New option field '+ counter +'"><i class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-minus" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button></i></div>');
    counter++;        
});

$(document).on('click', 'button.btn-minus', function(){
    $(this).parents('div.input-group').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="index" method="post">     
        <div id="optionsList"class="form-group">
            <label>Options</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="option1" placeholder="M S Dhoni">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="option2" placeholder="Virat Kohli">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="moreOptions">Add More Options</button>
        </div>          
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a onclick handler when you generate your button as following :

```
$("#removeBtn" + optionNo + "").click(function()
{
 $("#inputField" + optionNo + "").remove();
});
```